# json_encode equivalent for objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, encoding

I need to write the equivalent to this php code

```
json_encode(utf8_encode())
```

in objective-c

I've implemented the equivalent to utf8_encode with

```
[NSString stringWithCString:[testString cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]
```

So now, I need to implement the equivalent to json_encode php function.

input : "http://www.mydomain.com/s?c=Théâtre,Cinéma"

expected output :  "http://www.mydomain.com/s?c=Th\u00c3\u00a9\u00c3\u00a2tre,Cin\u00c3\u00a9ma"

Does anyone have an efficient way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could have a look at

```
+ (NSData *)dataWithJSONObject:(id)obj options:(NSJSONWritingOptions)opt error:(NSError **)error
```

You get back JSON data from some object of Apples Foundation classes. If you need a string, you could use:

```
- (id)initWithData:(NSData *)data encoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding
```

of NSString. Might result in something like:

```
NSString *string = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:YOUR_OBJECT_HERE options:0 error:nil] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];
```