# Simple JSON Framework for iOS 5 SDK

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, xcode4, ios5

i need to parse simple JSON php in my tableview for that i searched and tried loy but didnt get it. please suggest me proper link from where i can download the same.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2256625/comparison-of-json-parser-for-objective-c-json-framework-yajl-touchjson-etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personnaly i'm using SBJson

http://stig.github.com/json-framework/

it work pretty well

You can see an usage example here : http://jasarien.com/?p=428

Answer (score 1):

I hope one of my former posts can help you. I think this is what you inteded: [json_encode equivalent for objective-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10821272/json-encode-equivalent-for-objective-c/10821637#10821637)

Please note that this is **only available in iOS 5 and later**. If you need other solutions you'll have to use something like [this](http://blog.zachwaugh.com/post/309924609/how-to-use-json-in-cocoaobjective-c).

Answer (score 1):

JSONKit : https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit

MTJSON : https://github.com/mysterioustrousers/MTJSON

Comment: yajl-objc : https://github.com/gabriel/yajl-objc
TouchJSON : https://github.com/TouchCode/TouchJSON
JSON-FrameWork : https://github.com/stig/json-framework/